# Saving button text, path and icon when application closed

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have made a little program that can start application (like quick launch in your taskbar)
You can add applications and it shows the icon of the .exe and the name of the file, and when you click on it (button) it starts the application.

When you close the program and start it again everything is empty, so i want to save it somewhere.

I see people on the internet do it with:

```
    private void QuickStarter_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.Button1 = button1.Text;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }

    private void QuickStarter_Load(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.Button1;
    }
```

This doesn't work, but they use it for text fields and input boxes i don't know if it is even possible for a button.

**Question:**
Can someone tell me what the best way is, for saving button input and load it back in when the application starts again? Or maybe i have to do it with a label or something?

**Some little snippet that i use:**

```
   private void QuickStarter_Load(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.Button1;
    }

    Icon ico = null;
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    string[] fileNames = new string[5];

    private void application1ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ofd.Filter = "EXE|*.exe";
        ofd.Title = "Add application";

        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            ico = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(ofd.FileName);
            button1.Text = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(ofd.FileName);
            button1.Image = ico.ToBitmap();
            button1.Enabled = true;
            fileNames[0] = ofd.FileName;
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
        start.FileName = fileNames[0];
        Process.Start(start);
    }

    private void QuickStarter_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.Button1 = button1.Text;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Verifying the complaint

Using the following code works just fine for me, clicking the button will set the new text and closing and reloading the application will tell me when the button was last clicked.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        button1.Text = Settings.Default.button1;
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e) {
        Settings.Default.button1 = button1.Text;
        Settings.Default.Save();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        button1.Text = string.Format("Button was clicked at {0}", DateTime.Now);
    }
```

You might have a problem with your applications permissions, if it isn't allowed to write to the %appdata% subfolders it won't be able to store the settings.
But it's also entirely possible you have some other problem in your solution. One that isn't immediately clear from your description. Make a minimal test project (like i did) and verify that you can't save and retrieve settings on a brand new test project.

## Answering your question

Whenever you ask something along the lines of `What is the optimal way to ...` you are not going to get a conclusive answer and if i know anything about Stack Overflow i would say it's discouraged when you ask your question.

That said, here's how i would have done it.

1. Create a collection of data objects that implements the Serializable attributes. See [Introducing XML Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. That collection would hold properties that describe your buttons, the text, the executable and (if applicable) their position using a `Point` structure.
3. I would deserialize that on load and serialize it on close (or better yet, when something changes)
4. I would (after deserialization) iterate the data objects in that collection and dynamically create the buttons at runtime, adding them to the `Form`'s `Controls` like so:
   `Controls.Add(new Button { Text = "This is a new button!"});`
5. I would also add some controls to add/remove entries from your data object collection. Or by using a context menu, either way works. Your design, your decisions.
6. As you get more confident with your coding you can move on to dragging and dropping buttons to order them or position them in your 'quicklaunch' application.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the button1 property to the Settings in the Settings.Designer.cs (or use the Settings.settings grid.

You also need to make sure that the "QuickStarter_FormClosed" event is fired when you're window is closed.

This is my **Settings.Designer.cs:**

```
namespace SettingsSaveTest.Properties {


[global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsDesigner.SettingsSingleFileGenerator", "12.0.0.0")]
internal sealed partial class Settings : global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase {

    private static Settings defaultInstance = ((Settings)(global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.Synchronized(new Settings())));

    public static Settings Default {
        get {
            return defaultInstance;
        }
    }

    [global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("")]
    public string ButtonText {
        get {
            return ((string)(this["ButtonText"]));
        }
        set {
            this["ButtonText"] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

}
I didn't notice it was for Windows Forms, and not WPF, but the same thing applies, you need to add the property to your settings.designer.

Here is my version in **Windows Forms:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       button1.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.button1;
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Text = "Saving...";
    }
    private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        SaveProperties();
    }

    private void SaveProperties()
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.button1 = textBox1.Text;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Text = textBox1.Text;
    }
}
```

I also added the FormClosed eventhandler to the FormClosed stack:

```
this.FormClosed += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventHandler(this.Form1_FormClosed);
```

I am also leaving my answer for WPF, since some other people might wonder. But the same thing applies. You need to add the property, and configure the event listeners.

This is my **MainWindow.cs:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Button1.Content = Properties.Settings.Default.ButtonText;
        Closed += SaveSettings;
    }

    private void SaveSettings(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveProperties();
    }

    private void SaveProperties()
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.ButtonText = UserInput.Text;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       SaveProperties();
       Button1.Content =  Properties.Settings.Default.ButtonText;
    }
}
```

And finally my **MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="SettingsSaveTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="UserInput" x:FieldModifier="public" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="48,105,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    <Button x:Name="Button1" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="203,105,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button1_Click"/>

</Grid>
```

Comment: `add the button1 property to the Settings`, if that was the case... missing the property in his settings.designer.cs, his code wouldn't compile now would it?